# Django, capturing client IP getting

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to capture a client IP and store that into a log in my database, I have tried using packages like ipware but I am still getting the same error when I run my application

```
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/tutorial/drftutorial/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import views
File "/Users/abdul/Documents/tutorial/drftutorial/views.py", line 24, in <module>
class UserCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
File "/Users/abdul/Documents/tutorial/drftutorial/views.py", line 27, in UserCreateView
ip=get_client_ip(request)
File "/Users/abdul/Documents/tutorial/drftutorial/views.py", line 17, in get_client_ip
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'META'
```

I believe the error Is happening because I am not accessing the request method properly, I am using Django-restframework and the tutorial I followed did not pass the request object when calling the view.

here is my code:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

class UserCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    action = 'User registered'
    response1 = 'Success'
    ip=get_client_ip(request)
    print ip
    if ip is not None:
        ip="could not get IP"
    else:
        print(" got the IP!")
    print (" I am here!")
    Logadd(action,response1,ip)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Assuming the indentation is correct (and you've just not copy/pasted correctly here)... why isn't all that code inside a `post` function in `UserCreateView`?

Comment: or if your are using rest-framework inside `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @BearBrown ahh yes... it's a `CreateModelMixin`...

Comment: Just to note - the logic for yoru print statement is reversed: `if ip is not None` shouldn't be "could not get IP"...

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' in request.META:
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: in this case main trouble not in `get_client_ip` but in the place where it call